# How to get saml token from ADFS in .Net Core app

Tags: .net-core, saml, saml-2.0, adfs

I have a .Net core micro service. I need to talk to other service to get the data. But the other service needs saml token to return the data and they provided urls(relying party, adfs), credentials, certificate thumbprint for authentication. How to get the saml token? I found the logic below for .Net standard, but i want the same for .net core application.

```
var stsEndpoint = "https://MyAdfsServer/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed";
var reliantPartyUri = "https://MyDomain/AppRoot/";

var factory = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannelFactory(
            new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
            new EndpointAddress(stsEndpoint));

factory.TrustVersion = System.ServiceModel.Security.TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

// Username and Password here...
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = @"Domain\UserName";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "Password"

var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
        AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(reliantPartyUri),
        KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
    };

var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
var token = channel.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;

var saml = token.TokenXml.OuterXml;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you included is for using WS-Trust to return a SAML security token. This is different from using the SAML protocol for authentication. I suspect the other service is supporting the SAML v2.0 protocol rather than WS-Trust. You should confirm this with them.

If that's the case, I suggest taking a look at our [SAML library](https://www.componentspace.com/saml-for-asp-net-core) for ASP.NET Core apps. There are also open-source offerings.